# Typeahead options not displaying

Tags: angular, typescript

I need an assistance on this code i am currently writing, i am getting data from a remote service which i did successfully as it shows in the log, the problem now is the typeahead doesn't show options upon clicking. kindly assist.

i have consulted blogs and other stackoverflow questions relating it but no results.

Below are my code

TS

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css'],
  providers: [HomeServiceService]
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
   title = 'Autocomplete Example in Angular 6';

  

   searchTerm: FormControl = new FormControl();
   myDestination = <any>[];

   constructor (private service: HomeServiceService){

   }


   


  ngOnInit(): void {

    this.searchTerm.valueChanges.subscribe(
      term => {
        if ( term != ''){
          this.service.search(term).subscribe(
            data => {
              this.myDestination = data as any[];
              console.log(this.myDestination)
            
            }
          )
        }

        
      }
    )
```

service.ts

```
@Injectable()
export class HomeServiceService {

  constructor(private httpClient : HttpClient) { }

  search(term){

    var listOfBooks = this.httpClient.get('http://192.168.88.250:8080/api/v1/searchterminals/?searchTerm=' + term)
    .pipe(
      debounceTime(500),
      map(
        (data: any) => {
          return (
            data.length != 0 ? data as any[] : [{"BookName" : "No Record Found"} as any]
          );
        }
      )
    )
    return listOfBooks;
  }
```

html

```
 <mat-form-field class="container" >

          <input type="text" placeholder="Search destination ..."
                matInput 
                [formControl]="searchTerm" 
                [matAutocomplete]="auto">  
  
  
                <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete">
  
                  <mat-option *ngFor="let destination of this.myDestination.name" [value]="destination.name">
                      
                      {{ destination.name}}
                      {{ destination.city.name}}
                      
                  </mat-option>

                </mat-autocomplete>
  
      </mat-form-field>
```

Comment: can you try removing the `.name` part in your `*ngFor`? should look like this: `*ngFor="let destination of this.myDestination"`... also consider using better typing. Using any is usually considered an anti-pattern

Comment: i added the .name because its in an array so its l looping through it, if i remove the .name i will get errors regarding errors and iterables

Comment: You should probably figure out what you're assigning `myDestination` to. The property `name` doesn't exist on arrays, so its certainly not an array. Start by replacing every `any` in your code with a type or interface you wrote. That will probably point the mistake out to you.

Answer (score 0):

I have noticed three problems.

1. In your .HTML, your *ngFor loop is wrong.
   You're iterating over `this.myDestination.name`, which doesn't exist on the array "myDestination" and is not a property of the Array class. Remove the '.name' from your `*ngFor` loop to iterate successfully. In the comments, you mentioned other errors, this could be related your second line in the loop where you are accessing `destination.city.name` which is accessing `.name` of `undefined`.

Based on your service.TS file, your array would have the structure `[{BookName: string}]`. To visualise it, you can write it out:
`const myDestination = [{"BookName" : "No Record Found"}]`, which if you play around with your IDE in the TS, it will help you with understanding that neither `.name` exists on the array as a property, and neither is it set as a variable on any of the items in the array:

[image]

And neither does it exist on iterated items:
[image]

Which leads into the second problem I noticed:
2. In your .HTML, you're asking Angular to print out the value `destination.city.name`, which doesn't exist, either:
[image]

3. In your home.component.ts, at declaration you're casting myDestination to type `any`, which confuses the IDE to guide you that it is indeed an array. Instead, write this: `myDestination: Array<any> = []`. Read more about casting [here](https://www.typescripttutorial.net/typescript-tutorial/type-casting/) and Type Assertion [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html).

When you write your code out like this, it will help you understand that Angular is only as capable as the JavaScript (Typescript) you give it.
Have a look in the [official documentation](https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf) to learn more.

Some highly opinionated jargon:

- Naming of arrays should be plural - *myDestination***s**
- Don't use type `any` unless absolutely necessary.
- Using plugins like [Angular Language Service](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Angular.ng-template) (or alike for your IDE) will assist you to detect these problems sooner.
- DebounceTime should be used before calling a service (or at least, before calling the API) and not on the response.

Comment: i got the response

'[object Object]'. Only arrays and iterables are allowed